# SQL Query to Pars Out a Value from NTEXT (XML format) field

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have XML data in an NTEXT field (ou.ORDMODE), that I need to parse out a value (description) from. Column may contain null values. The data looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<UDFValidatedValue xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Accellos.Platform.UDF">
  <Description>Export</Description>
  <Value>EXP</Value>
  <ValueType>String</ValueType>
</UDFValidatedValue>
```

The line I have in my query is this:

```
CAST(REPLACE(CAST(ou.ORDMODE as NVARCHAR(MAX)),' xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Accellos.Platform.UDF"','') as XML).value ('(/UDFValidatedValue/Description/text())[0]', 'nvarchar(100)') as Mode3,
```

but Mode3 column is returned as blank.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please tag with database platform, and show a [mcve]

Comment: Database platform tagged. Would appreciate some feedback on how to improve the question.

Comment: It's because XML/XPath uses one-based indexing. e.g. Change `text())[0]` to `text())[1]`. And, actually, you shouldn't even really need the `text()` part, just `(/UDFValidatedValue/Description)[1]` would do.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Made the suggested changes, but the field is still returned blank.

Comment: @ZLK, You might [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43242238/5089204)... Using `/text()` is not just syntax sugar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this:

```
DEclare @xml xml = N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<UDFValidatedValue xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Accellos.Platform.UDF">
 <Description>Export</Description>
 <Value>EXP</Value>
 <ValueType>String</ValueType>
</UDFValidatedValue>';            

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Accellos.Platform.UDF')
select @xml.value ('(/UDFValidatedValue/Description)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as Mode3
```

or

```
select @xml.value ('declare namespace 
         udf="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Accellos.Platform.UDF";
         (/udf:UDFValidatedValue/udf:Description)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as Mode3
```

Demo link: [Rextester](http://rextester.com/IKDXX14703)

Answer (score 0):

As ZLK pointed out in his comment, your own approach seems to be quite okay, just the index must be 1 instead of 0. Try it here:

ad *"quite okay"*: Actually this is absolutely far away from *"quite okay"*, read my hint below...

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(SomeXmlInText TEXT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<UDFValidatedValue xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Accellos.Platform.UDF">
  <Description>Export</Description>
  <Value>EXP</Value>
  <ValueType>String</ValueType>
</UDFValidatedValue>');

SELECT SomeXmlInText
      ,CAST(REPLACE(CAST(SomeXmlInText as NVARCHAR(MAX)),' xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Accellos.Platform.UDF"','') as XML).value ('(/UDFValidatedValue/Description/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as Mode3
FROM @tbl
```

From your answer I take, that there is still no result...

Some possible issues:

- XML is not really as you expect it
- more / other namespaces
- some weird *no, not for you* issue :-D

### Hint

As you probably know `TEXT`, `NTEXT` and `IMAGE` are deprecated for centuries and should really not be used any more... If you have the slightest chance to change this, then you should store your XML in the appropritate XML-type...

You should not need any casts or manipulations on string level. This can be working, but is really out-dated...