# Need help in retrieving XML data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I need help in retrieving the data from this XML that is stored in a column in a SQL Server table. I've been searching the questions repository but couldn't find any that matches mine. Maybe i missed out somehow. Anyway, here how the stored XML looks like :

```
<ProductStructure>
  <Plans>Essential</Plans>
  <Plans>Standard</Plans>
  <Plans>Silver</Plans>
  <Plans>Gold</Plans>
  <Plans>Platinum</Plans>
  <Plans>Titanium</Plans>
  <Destinations>Region A</Destinations>
  <Destinations>Region B</Destinations>
  <Destinations>Region C</Destinations>
  <Destinations>Region D</Destinations>
  <InsuredTypes>One Person</InsuredTypes>
  <InsuredTypes>Couple</InsuredTypes>
  <InsuredTypes>Group</InsuredTypes>
</ProductStructure>
```

I would like to select the xml and get an output like below in SQL:

```
|Plans          |Essential    |
|               |Standard     |
|               |Silver       |
|               |Gold         |
|               |Platinum     |
|               |Titanium     |
|---------------+-------------|
|Destinations   |Region A     |
|               |Region B     |
|               |Region C     |
|               |Region D     |
|---------------+-------------|
|InsuredTypes   |One Person   |
|               |Couple       |
|               |Group        |
```

Sorry for if the question was visualized badly. Thank you.

Comment: Something like this would work for your data: `SELECT Field = A.B.value('local-name(.)', 'VARCHAR(255)'), Val = A.B.value('text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(255)') FROM @XML.nodes('ProductStructure/*') AS A(B);`

Comment: @ZLK holy smokes. You made it looks like child's play. Thank you good sir. It worked. You really saved the hassle for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @xml xml = N'<ProductStructure>
  <Plans>Essential</Plans>
  <Plans>Standard</Plans>
  <Plans>Silver</Plans>
  <Plans>Gold</Plans>
  <Plans>Platinum</Plans>
  <Plans>Titanium</Plans>
  <Destinations>Region A</Destinations>
  <Destinations>Region B</Destinations>
  <Destinations>Region C</Destinations>
  <Destinations>Region D</Destinations>
  <InsuredTypes>One Person</InsuredTypes>
  <InsuredTypes>Couple</InsuredTypes>
  <InsuredTypes>Group</InsuredTypes>
</ProductStructure>'

SELECT
    t.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)'),
    t.value('.','nvarchar(max)')
FROM @xml.nodes('ProductStructure/*') AS t(t)
```

And you'll get:

```
-------------------- --------------------
Plans                Essential
Plans                Standard
Plans                Silver
Plans                Gold
Plans                Platinum
Plans                Titanium
Destinations         Region A
Destinations         Region B
Destinations         Region C
Destinations         Region D
InsuredTypes         One Person
InsuredTypes         Couple
InsuredTypes         Group
```

You can group results as you want.

Comment: Thank you sir. It works. I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: This is okay, but could be improved. ZLK's comment shows how... You might [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43242238/5089204), why `.value(N'text()[1]',...)` or `.value(N'(./text())[1]',...)` is better than just `.value('.',...)`. Furthermore it is recommended to be as specific as possible. So `.nodes(N'/ProductStructure/*')` is better than `.nodes('*/*')`. Anyway, good answer! +1 from my side

Comment: @Shnugo thank you for your comment, feel free to edit my answer, if you think, you can improve it