# T-SQL XML node value

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I'm trying to extract the values from the following xml document

```
<response> 
  <entry>
    <title>the tales</title>
    <subject-area code="1" abbrev="XX1">Test1</subject-area>
    <subject-area code="2" abbrev="XX2">Test2</subject-area>
  </entry>
</response>
```

but I'm having problem getting the subject-area text values i.e. "Test1"

I'm using the below T-SQL to extract the rest of the values, I'm using a cross appy on the node as I required this to loop to get all values so can't use [1] etc to extract it that way as I'm not sure how many subject area there will be.

Any ideas

```
SELECT
    ,a.APIXMLResponse.value('(response[1]/entry[1]/title[1])','VARCHAR(250)') AS Title
    ,sa.value('(./@code)','varchar(10)') AS SubjectAreaCode
    ,sa.value('(./@abbrev)','varchar(10)') AS SubjectAreaAbbrev
FROM [dbo].[APIXML] a
CROSS APPLY APIXMLResponse.nodes('response/entry/subject-area') AS SubjectArea(sa)
```

Comment: `value('.', 'varchar(1000)')`

Comment: Thanks, I was just returning to the forum to say I'd literally just figured it out, think I'll need a break as it was obvious and staring me in the face :-)

 ,sa.value('(.)[1]','varchar(10)') SubjectArea

Comment: @IvanStarostin Although this is working, one must be very careful using `'.'` in `.value()`. You might follow the link in my answer to find details.

Answer (score 0):

Although there is a working solution in a comment already, I'd like to point out some things:

- Using just `'.'` as path can lead to very annoying effects, if there are nested elements.
- Looking for performance it is recommended to use `text()[1]` to read the needed value at its actual place ([Here are some details with examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43242238/5089204)).
- As the internal values are `NVARCHAR(x)` it is slightly faster to use `NVARCHAR` as target type (if you don't have a reason to do otherwise...

That's my query:

```
SELECT
     a.APIXMLResponse.value('(response/entry/title)[1]','NVARCHAR(250)') AS Title
    ,sa.value('@code','nvarchar(10)') AS SubjectAreaCode
    ,sa.value('@abbrev','nvarchar(10)') AS SubjectAreaAbbrev
    ,sa.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(10)') AS SubjectAreaContent
FROM @mockup a
CROSS APPLY APIXMLResponse.nodes('response/entry/subject-area') AS SubjectArea(sa)
```