# How to shred XML value in to a column in MSSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, xml-parsing

Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @xml XML
set @xml ='
<settings>
<value>1306</value>
<value>1307</value>
<value>1310</value>
</settings>'


select tabl.col.value ('value[1]','int')
from @xml.nodes ('/settings') tabl (col)
cross apply tabl.col.nodes ('value') as tabl1 (col1)
```

Output received :

---

1306

1306

1306

Excepted output:

---

1306

1307

1310

Please point out where my mistake is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `cross apply`, you can directly express it as

```
select tabl.col.value ('.','int')
from @xml.nodes ('settings/value') tabl (col);
```

Comment: This answer is a good one (+1 from my side), but I'd replace the `.` with `text()[1]`. You might [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43242238/5089204) to understand why. In this easy case it's perfectly okay though. And - in general - it's recommended to start with a single `/` in order to mark the entry point as the root element (`/settings/value`).

Comment: Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 1):

> Please point out where my mistake is...

```
select tabl.col.value ('value[1]','int')
from @xml.nodes ('/settings') tabl (col)
cross apply tabl.col.nodes ('value') as tabl1 (col1)
```

Your mistake: `from @xml.nodes()` is not pulling the repeating element `<value>` but is calling for `<settings>`. There is one single element. Now you pick the first value ('value[1]'). This would return 1 row with "1306".

But you add a `cross apply` with a *relativ* reference to `<value>` below `<settings>`. This does return 3 rows, but the results are not used anywhere.

Therefore you get the single result 1306 repeated for each row.

The solution how to solve this is given in the other answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation