# How to retrieve data from XML column in sql server with no element name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have XML like this in a column of a SQL Server table:

```
<Sales>
  <customer>
    <custID>6886903</custID>
    <placeID>143144</placeID>UNKNOWN</customer>

</Sales>
```

How to retrieve UNKNOWN from above when it doesn't have any element name?

Comment: At [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43242238/5089204) you find some examples about `text()` nodes and how the might *float* within their element.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the `UNKNOWN` text belongs to the `customer` element.

```
DECLARE @data XML
SELECT  @data = '<Sales>
  <customer>
    <custID>6886903</custID>
    <placeID>143144</placeID>UNKNOWN</customer>

</Sales>'

SELECT  p.value('(./custID)[1]' , 'int') AS custID,
        p.value('(./placeID)[1]', 'int') AS placeID,
        p.value('(./text())[1]' , 'varchar(max)') AS customerName
FROM    @data.nodes('/Sales/customer') t(p)
```

Comment: Good answer, you might read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43242238/5089204) about some details on `text()`